# Is using hard-coded integer values in code a BAD practice from memory considerations

Tags: java, jvm

Consider a simple following code in Java:

```
void func(String test)
{
    if(str.length() > 0)
    {
       //do something
    }
}
```

Does executing str.length() > 0 means that every time this function is called, 4 bytes of memory will be allocated to store 0 integer value ?

Comment: if your memory consideration is only about these integers, then all I say is woooow =)

Comment: No, in fact here there is a jump-on-positive. But there are load constant instructions, and only the class file is a bit larger. Even constants are shared in the .class file.

Answer (score 2):

The memory needed to run this function (including the `0`) would be part of the compiled program (.class / .jar/.apk), and has **nothing to do with how many times the function is run**. Even **if the function is inlined**, only the code size **grows based on how many different locations the function is called**, and there is **NO memory allocation in run time**, while the code runs.

Meanwhile 2 comments

- There are **far** bigger issues with hardcoding.
- I doubt `length > 0` counts as hardcoding in any but the strictest sense.

Comment: OK. From your and @Joop comments, i understand that constants used in a method are taken care by the compiler to be available always during runtime so that we avoid allocating memory again and again for the same constant value.
Can you please refer some study material on this.

Answer (score 2):

If you write clean, clear and simple code the JIT will optimise the code best in 95+% of cases. If you attempt to out smart it, it is far more likely you will make the code worse, not better.

There are been some notable exceptions to this rule, but these tend to only last a few years.  For example Locks in Java 5.0 were much faster than synchronized, however in Java 7 synchronized can be much faster.

When considering performance you should look at the behaviour of the whole system, not individual lines of code or even individual libraries.  Failing to do this can mean you spend time worrying about something which makes no difference while a much more important thing is being ignored.

I have seen whole teams work on optimising a piece of a system for years when they could have made the whole thing faster just be changing a configuration setting.  This is because they limited their view to the code they were writing, and didn't consider how they used the systems they connected to. Imagine wasting years of work when they could have seen more of a speed up with something trivial, and make sure this doesn't happen to you. ;)

Answer (score 0):

No memory allocations are done when this code executes.

Answer (score 0):

Its not looking anything serious in the above code as memory allocation point of view.

> if(str.length() > 0) { }

Here its genuine requirement for comparision so it wont be consider as hard coding values.

If you are very strict towards memory utilization then always pick exact required data type.

Answer (score 0):

This code is method local, hence after executing memory will reclaim automatically.
AS it is inside method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but destroyed immediately after exiting the function. `int` is `primitive type`. Primitive types are considered the fastest in Java. So, I think it won't cost much.